# Export Web SQL database to a text file and mail it to the user in Phonegap project using javascript code

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-sql

I have 5 tables in my web SQL database. I want to export this data into a text file using Javascript code.

This text file needs to be stored in Phone's local storage.

Then this needs to be sent via email using JS code only.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Connect to websql using javascript:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my db', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var data = "";
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ' + tablename, [], function (tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length, i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      data += results.rows.item(i).text;
    }
  });
});
```

Once you have the data; either directly mail it using [cordova email plugin.](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

```
window.plugin.email.open({
    to:          Array, // email addresses for TO field
    cc:          Array, // email addresses for CC field
    bcc:         Array, // email addresses for BCC field
    attachments: Array, // paths to the files you want to attach or base64 encoded data streams
    subject:    String, // subject of the email
    body:       String, // email body (could be HTML code, in this case set isHtml to true)
    isHtml:    Boolean, // indicats if the body is HTML or plain text
}, callback, scope);
```

Or [write it to a file](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html), on *write end* call the above method with path to attachment